# How to get cookies of a specific android app without root?

Tags: android, cookies, session-cookies

I want to get cookies of a specific android apps without any root. I don't want to connect the device to computer.
Is it possible to do that?

I tried to do that using ProxyDroid, NetCapture. But unable to get any data.
But NetCapture app able to catch the data, but it says, there are no data in that  file.